# How do I extract ecdf values out of ecdfplot()

Tags: r, extract, lattice, ecdf

If I use the `ecdfplot()` function of the `latticeExtra` package how do I get the actual values calculated i.e. the y-values which correspond to the `~x|g` input?

I've been looking at `?ecdfplot` but there's not discription to it. For the usual highlevel function `ecdf()` it works with the command `plot=FALSE` but this does not work for `ecdfplot()`.

The reason I want to use `ecdfplot()` rather than `ecdf()` is that I need to calculate the `ecdf()` values for a grouping variable. I know I could do this handish too but I'm quite convinced that there is a highroad too.

Here a small expample

```
u <- rnorm(100,0,1)
mygroup <- c(rep("group1",50),rep("group2",50))
ecdfplot(~u, groups=mygroup)
```

[image]

I would like to extract the y-values given each group for the corresponding x-values.

Comment: Could you include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) of `ecdfplot` and how you're using it? It would make your question much easier to answer.

Comment: ok ill edit one in just a second plz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know you said you don't want to use `ecdf`, but in this case it is *much* easier to use it than to get the data out of the [trellis](http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/trellis.html) object that `ecdfplot` returns. (After all, that's all that `ecdfplot` is doing- it's just doing it behind the scenes).

In the case of your example, the following will get you a matrix of the y values (where `x` is your entire input `u`, though you could choose a different one) for each ECDF:

```
ecdfs = lapply(split(u, mygroup), ecdf)
ys = sapply(ecdfs, function(e) e(u))
# output:
#       group1 group2
#  [1,]   0.52   0.72
#  [2,]   0.68   0.78
#  [3,]   0.62   0.78
#  [4,]   0.66   0.78
#  [5,]   0.72   0.80
#  [6,]   0.86   0.94
#  [7,]   0.10   0.26
#  [8,]   0.90   0.94
# ...
```

ETA: If you just want each column to correspond to the 50 x-values in that column, you could do:

```
ys = sapply(split(u, mygroup), function(g) ecdf(g)(g))
```

(Note that if the number of values in each group aren't identical, this will end up as a list rather than a matrix with columns).

Comment: Thx very much. I probably took the more difficult approach then :)

Comment: You're very welcome. By the way, if this answered your question you can [accept it as an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: Not a problem. By the way (and this is not to pressure or scold you), I happened to notice there were a few other questions you asked that had excellent answers that hadn't been accepted. If you do accept them (though you are not obligated to do so), you'll get yourself a few reputation points, reward the people who helped, and ensure that people reading your question in the future know what worked.

Comment: oh ok thats a bad on my part. maybe i can still accept them :) ill have a look. im not so much into point hunting but if others benefit it surely matters. so i accepted all the others which provided me with a good answer :). thx again

Comment: ive a quick question about your answer: ill get for each factor of the grouping variable n y-values corresponding to the ecdf function. but in the example each group only got n1=n2=50 observations. do i know take from the table which you provided that y-value which corresponds to the grouping factor i.e. if x1 is from group1 ill take the left value, if x2 is from group2 ill take the right value?

Comment: See my edit above. There are other ways you could arrange this data- I'm sure you can figure them out based on these examples.

Answer (score 11):

If you stick with the ecdf() function in the base package, you can simply do as follows:

1. Create ecdf function with your data:

   ```
   fun.ecdf <- ecdf(x) # x is a vector of your data
   ```
2. Now use this "ecdf function" to generate the cumulative probabilities of any vector you feed it, including your original, sorted data:

   ```
   my.ecdf <- fun.ecdf(sort(x))
   ```

Comment: but how do you do this for say, 50 cols,variables?

Comment: @ElChapo `data <- matrix(rnorm(100), 10, 10); apply(data, 2, function(x) ecdf(x)(sort(x)))`