# How to extract Ecdf value from the Ecdf() return？

Tags: r, list, ecdf

The answer for [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12169502/how-do-i-extract-ecdf-values-out-of-ecdfplot) question here suggest a way by applying `ecdf`.

However I am using `Ecdf()` from package `Hmisc` for it provides a convenient way to do a ccdf(Complementary Cumulative Distribution Function) plot. (by setting the `what` option to '1-F')

By default, `Ecdf()` does the plot and return a nested list containing `x` and `y`.

How can I extract the `y` value of a certain `x` value? and then plot it on the original plot?

FYI:

```
 > str(Ecdf(rnorm(20), lwd = 2))
    List of 2
     $ x: num [1:21] -1.46 -1.46 -1.18 -1.17 -1.16 ...
     $ y: num [1:21] 0 0.05 0.1 0.15 0.2 0.25 0.3 0.35 0.4 0.45 ...
     - attr(*, "N")=List of 2
      ..$ n: num 20
      ..$ m: num 0
```

At first i am considering convert this list to a data.frame using methods suggested from [R List to Data Frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227223/r-list-to-data-frame), but my data is huge and the `rbind` seems really slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Ecdf` returns a list whereas `ecdf` returns a function. It's a lot easier to use the R-stats function `ecdf` than it is to use something tortured like: `Ecdf(.)$y[ min(which(Ecdf(.)$x>val))]`.  If you want the value of ecdf(x=0) from an `Ecdf-object` then this should work:

```
 ecdf( Ecdf(rnorm(20), lwd = 2)$x ) (v=0)
[1] 0.5238095
```

(It turns out that the formal parameter for the function returned by `ecdf` is "v".) But if you want the less elegant method and you already have assigned the result to an object named 'oneEcdf':

```
oneEcdf <- Ecdf(rnorm(20), lwd = 2)
oneEcdf$y[ min( which(oneEcdf$x > 0 ))]
[1] 0.6
```