# How to get data of a ks plot

Tags: r, plot

I ploted a Kolmogorov-Smirnov test of weather data, using a Gumbel fit.

```
ks.gumbel(data$mm, 63.2899, 30.06080, alternative = "two.sided", plot = TRUE)
```

And I want to get the x value of the curve ploted in y=0.996.

Any ideas? thanks !

Comment: Please specify the package used.

Comment: I used reliaR package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the source code for `ks.gumbel`, the plot is generated by `plot(ecdf(x))`, but no value from the plot is returned from the function.  So it will be impossible to get the information you seek directly from `ks.gumbel`, but we do know enough to be able to get in ourselves.

Using an answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/16819127/1017276 and combining this knowledge with `uniroot`, we can solve the function returned by `ecdf` to return the value of `x` at the desired value of `y`.

```
uniroot(f = function(x) ecdf(data$mm)(v = x) - .996,
        interval = range(data$mm, na.rm = TRUE))
```

The `root` element of the list returned by `uniroot` will give you the value you are looking for.